# Numba Kalman Filter and Smoother Implementation

Tags: python, numpy, numba, kalman-filter

I am building a Kalman filter and smoother into an application and would like to use numba `@njit` with parallelization for high performance. Specifically, I have a panel of many time series (many "individuals") that can be filtered and smoothed independently, hence the desire for parallelization with `prange`. I am having an error when numba attempts to compile my code. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
from numba import prange, jit, njit

# Note on notation here: 't' means conditional on time t. 
#                        'tl1' means conditional on time t-1
#                         or time lagged one

@njit(parallel=False) #  parallel=False for now
def kalman_filter(Y,Q,R,B,F,z0,sig110,sig120):
    """
    Estimate Kalman filter and smoother given model parameter estimates. Uses numba and 
    parallelization for high performance.
    
    Arguments
    ----------
    Y: np.array 
        Array of measurements y_{i,t}. Dimension shall be TxN where 
        T is the number of time periods and N is the number of individuals.
    Q: np.array 
        Array of volatilities of the state equation. Dimension shall 
        be TxN where T is the number of time periods and N is the 
        number of individuals.
    R: np.array 
        Array of volatilities of the measurement equation. Dimension shall 
        be TxN where T is the number of time periods and N is the 
        number of individuals.
    B: np.array
        Array of drifts of the state equation. Dimension shall 
        be TxN where T is the number of time periods and N is the 
        number of individuals.
    F: np.array 
        Array of persistence in the state equation. Dimension shall 
        be TxN where T is the number of time periods and N is the 
        number of individuals.
    z0: np.array 
        Array of initial zeta by individual. Dimension shall be 2xN.
    sig110: np.array 
        Array of initial MSE_{i,t}[0,0]. Dimensions TxN.
    sig120: np.array 
        Array of initial MSE_{i,t}[0,1]. Dimensions TxN.
    
    Returns
    --------
    zeta_t: np.array
        Matrix of latent variable [z_{i,t}|t, z_{i,t-1}|t] estimated conditional on information at time t. 
        Dimension shall be TxNx2 where T is the number of time periods and N is the number of individuals.
    zeta_tl1: np.array
        Matrix of latent variable [z_{i,t}|t-1, z_{i,t-1}|t-1] estimated conditional on information at time t-1. 
        Dimension shall be TxNx2 where T is the number of time periods and N is the number of individuals.
    mse_t: np.array 
        Matrix MSE_t conditional on time t. Dimension TxNx2x2
    mse_tl1: np.array 
        Matrix MSE_t conditional on time t-1. Dimension TxNx2x2
    zeta_smooth: np.array 
        Array [z_{i,t}|T, z_{i,t-1}|T]. Dimensions TxNx2.
    mse_smooth: np.array 
        MSE_t conditional on time T for all i,t. Dimensions TxNx2x2.
    """
    
    # infer dimensions 
    T,N = Y.shape
    
    # iniitalize matrices
    zeta_t = np.zeros((T,N,2))
    zeta_tl1 = np.zeros((T,N,2))
    mse_t = np.zeros((T,N,2,2))
    mse_tl1 = np.zeros((T,N,2,2))
    zeta_smooth = np.zeros((T,N,2))
    mse_smooth = np.zeros((T,N,2,2))
    
    # set H
    H = np.array([[1.0,0.0]])
    
    # loop through individuals
    for i in prange(N):
        #zeta_t[:,i,:], zeta_tl1[:,i,:], mse_t[:,i,:,:], mse_tl1[:,i,:,:], zeta_smooth[:,i,:], mse_smooth[:,i,:,:] = kalman_filter_individual(
        #            Y[:,i],Q[:,i],R[:,i],B[:,i],F[:,i],z0[:,i].T,sig110[i],sig120[i],smooth)
        
        # initialize individual matrices 
        imse_t = np.zeros((T,2,2)) # MSE_{i,t}|t
        imse_tl1 = np.zeros((T,2,2)) # MSE_{i,t}|t-1
        izeta_t = np.zeros((T,2)) # zeta_{i,t}|t
        izeta_tl1 = np.zeros((T,2))  # zeta_{i,t}|t-1
        
        # initialize 
        imse_t[0,:,:] = np.array([[sig110[i],sig120[i]],[sig120[i],0]])
        imse_tl1[0,:,:] = np.array([[sig110[i],sig120[i]],[sig120[i],0]])
        izeta_t[0,0] = z0[0,i]
        izeta_tl1[1,0] = z0[0,i]
        
        # loop through time 
        for t in range(T):
            Ft = np.array([[F[i,t],0],[1,0]])
            gain = imse_tl1[t,:,:] @ H.T / (imse_tl1[t,0,0] + R[i,t])
            izeta_t[t,:] = izeta_tl1[t,:] + gain.flatten() * (Y[i,t] - H @ izeta_tl1[t,:])
            if t<T-1:
                izeta_tl1[t+1,:] = ( Ft @ izeta_t[t,:] + np.array([[B[i,t],0]]) ).flatten()
            imse_t[t,:,:] = imse_tl1[t,:,:] - gain @ H @ imse_tl1[t,:,:]
            if t<T-1:
                imse_tl1[t+1,:,:] = Ft @ imse_t[t,:,:] @ Ft.T + np.array([[Q[i,t],0],[0,0]])
        
        # Kalman Smoother 
        
        # initialize indivdual output
        imse_smooth = np.zeros((T,2,2))
        izeta_smooth = np.zeros((T,2))
        
        # calculate smoothed sequences
        izeta_smooth[T-1,:] = izeta_t[T-1,:]
        imse_smooth[T-1,:] = imse_t[T-1,:]
            
        for tt in range(T-1):
            t = (T-1) - tt # reverse range
            Ft = np.array([[F[i,t],0],[1,0]])
            J = imse_t[t,:] @ Ft.T @ np.linalg.inv(imse_tl1[t,:])
            izeta_smooth[t,:] = izeta_t[t,:] + J @ (izeta_smooth[t+1,:] - izeta_tl1[t+1,:])
            imse_smooth[t,:] = imse_t[t,:] + J @ (imse_smooth[t+1,:] - imse_tl1[t+1,:]) @ J.T
            
        # put individual arrays into main arrays 
        zeta_t[:,i,:] = izeta_t 
        zeta_tl1[:,i,:] = izeta_tl1 
        mse_t[:,i,:,:] = imse_t 
        mse_tl1[:,i,:,:] = imse_tl1 
        zeta_smooth[:,i,:] = izeta_smooth 
        mse_smooth[:,i,:,:] = imse_smooth
            
        
    return zeta_t, zeta_tl1, mse_t, mse_tl1, zeta_smooth, mse_smooth
```

Here is the error I get when numba attempts to compile:

```
C:\Users\damon\Documents\DamonDocuments\CareerEducation\lira\moat\generalized_kalman\pygenkalman\kalman_filter_numba.py:93: NumbaPerformanceWarning: '@' is faster on contiguous arrays, called on (array(float64, 2d, A), array(float64, 2d, F))
  gain = imse_tl1[t,:,:] @ H.T / (imse_tl1[t,0,0] + R[i,t])
C:\Users\damon\Documents\DamonDocuments\CareerEducation\lira\moat\generalized_kalman\pygenkalman\kalman_filter_numba.py:97: NumbaPerformanceWarning: '@' is faster on contiguous arrays, called on (array(float64, 2d, C), array(float64, 2d, A))
  imse_t[t,:,:] = imse_tl1[t,:,:] - gain @ H @ imse_tl1[t,:,:]
C:\Users\damon\Documents\DamonDocuments\CareerEducation\lira\moat\generalized_kalman\pygenkalman\kalman_filter_numba.py:99: NumbaPerformanceWarning: '@' is faster on contiguous arrays, called on (array(float64, 2d, C), array(float64, 2d, A))
  imse_tl1[t+1,:,:] = Ft @ imse_t[t,:,:] @ Ft.T + np.array([[Q[i,t],0],[0,0]])
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\damon\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py", line 356, in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File "c:\users\damon\documents\damondocuments\careereducation\lira\moat\generalized_kalman\pygenkalman\test.py", line 265, in <module>
    test_results = run_tests(test_list,parallel=False,verbose=10)

  File "c:\users\damon\documents\damondocuments\careereducation\lira\moat\generalized_kalman\pygenkalman\test.py", line 233, in run_tests
    result = m.estimate_model(battery[test]['fcns'], battery[test]['X'], Y, battery[test]['init'],

  File "C:\Users\damon\Documents\DamonDocuments\CareerEducation\lira\moat\generalized_kalman\pygenkalman\genkalman.py", line 90, in estimate_model
    zeta_t, zeta_tl1, mse_t, mse_tl1, zeta_smooth, mse_smooth = kfn.kalman_filter(Y,Q,R,B,F,z0,sig110,sig120)

  File "C:\Users\damon\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 487, in _compile_for_args
    raise e

  File "C:\Users\damon\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 420, in _compile_for_args
    return_val = self.compile(tuple(argtypes))

  File "C:\Users\damon\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 965, in compile
    cres = self._compiler.compile(args, return_type)

  File "C:\Users\damon\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 125, in compile
    status, retval = self._compile_cached(args, return_type)

  File "C:\Users\damon\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 139, in _compile_cached
    retval = self._compile_core(args, return_type)

  File "C:\Users\damon\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 152, in _compile_core
    cres = compiler.compile_extra(self.targetdescr.typing_context,

  File "C:\Users\damon\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\compiler.py", line 716, in compile_extra
    return pipeline.compile_extra(func)

  File "C:\Users\damon\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\compiler.py", line 452, in compile_extra
    return self._compile_bytecode()

  File "C:\Users\damon\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\compiler.py", line 520, in _compile_bytecode
    return self._compile_core()

  File "C:\Users\damon\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\compiler.py", line 499, in _compile_core
    raise e

  File "C:\Users\damon\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\compiler.py", line 486, in _compile_core
    pm.run(self.state)

  File "C:\Users\damon\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\compiler_machinery.py", line 368, in run
    raise patched_exception

  File "C:\Users\damon\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\compiler_machinery.py", line 356, in run
    self._runPass(idx, pass_inst, state)

  File "C:\Users\damon\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\compiler_lock.py", line 35, in _acquire_compile_lock
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\damon\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\compiler_machinery.py", line 311, in _runPass
    mutated |= check(pss.run_pass, internal_state)

  File "C:\Users\damon\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\compiler_machinery.py", line 273, in check
    mangled = func(compiler_state)

  File "C:\Users\damon\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\typed_passes.py", line 394, in run_pass
    lower.lower()

  File "C:\Users\damon\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\lowering.py", line 168, in lower
    self.lower_normal_function(self.fndesc)

  File "C:\Users\damon\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\lowering.py", line 222, in lower_normal_function
    entry_block_tail = self.lower_function_body()

  File "C:\Users\damon\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\lowering.py", line 251, in lower_function_body
    self.lower_block(block)

  File "C:\Users\damon\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\lowering.py", line 265, in lower_block
    self.lower_inst(inst)

  File "C:\Users\damon\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\lowering.py", line 439, in lower_inst
    val = self.lower_assign(ty, inst)

  File "C:\Users\damon\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\lowering.py", line 626, in lower_assign
    return self.lower_expr(ty, value)

  File "C:\Users\damon\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\lowering.py", line 1322, in lower_expr
    castvals = [self.context.cast(self.builder, val, fromty,

  File "C:\Users\damon\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\lowering.py", line 1322, in <listcomp>
    castvals = [self.context.cast(self.builder, val, fromty,

  File "C:\Users\damon\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\base.py", line 702, in cast
    return impl(self, builder, fromty, toty, val)

  File "C:\Users\damon\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\cpython\listobj.py", line 1137, in list_to_list
    assert fromty.dtype == toty.dtype

AssertionError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: native lowering)
```

Comment: I do not expect Numba to behave well on lines like `np.array([[F[i,t],0],[1,0]])`. Event if it would compile, it would be inefficient anyway... I advise you to create an array and fill it. This is the kind of think that should make your code more efficient and maybe solve the error (or make it at least more clear). In general, lists should be avoided in Numba. Loops and arrays should be preferred.

Comment: By the way, matrix multiplications typically run in parallel so if you run multiple matrix multiplication in parallel is can slow things down (eg. too many threads to schedule or conflits). Disabling BLAS parallelism help to fix such an issue, but it can slow down other part of your code. If matrices are guaranteed to be small, then it is better to use loops than high-level operation like that (which stab you in the back).

Comment: @JérômeRichard Thank you for the helpful tips. The matrices can be reasonably large. N in the low thousands and T between 0 and 100. I tried joblib with a dask backend instead of numba but that was quite slow. What would you suggest?

Comment: Numpy uses BLAS libraries for matrix multiplications. They are generally pretty optimized so it is very hard to outperform them, especially for relatively large matrices like here. Numba should do the same so it should not speed this up. You should profile the code (without Numba because profiling in Numba is a pain) so to check if loops are an issue but I do not expect them to be a bottleneck. Using plain loops can help to avoid temporary array that might decrease a slightly the performance (but if will certainly  make the matrix multiplication slower).

Comment: `np.linalg.inv` can be pretty expensive since it runs in `O(n**3)`. In general, people use mathematical tricks (eg. computing directly `x` from `Ax=b` without computing `inv(A)`) so to avoid a matrix inversion like the plague in computational applications. I do not know if this is possible here.

Comment: Put it shortly : *profile first*, then try the above advises based on profiling results.